# GeoServer on cascading WMTS sets wrong CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, wmts

I have one GeoServer 2.12.5 with a layer which CRS is set to EPSG:3857, and another GeoServer 2.14.2 where I want to cascade WMTS from the first one. But when I add this layer from cascaded source its native CRS is detected as EPSG:4326, not 3857. I even deleted 4326 gridset from tile options of original layer, but is didn't help. How to fix cascaded CRS?

Original layer group CRS-settings:
[image: Layer group CRS settings]

Original layer group gridset settings:
[image: Layer group grid settings]

In cascaded layer its CRS is detected as EPSG:4326
[image: detected CRS]

Answer (score 3):

It's a [known bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/issues/GEOS-9042), if this is important to you please consider sponsoring the work.

Comment: Is there a workaround? Does this bug relate only to WMTS in 2.14.2? In 2.12.5 I have same issue with cascading WMS. Is cascading feature is bugged in every version and for each protocol? BTW out of pure curiosity, is TDD used for GeoServer development?

Comment: It hasn't been fixed so it will continue in all versions since 2.14.x onwards. I believe all the test servers used defined epsg:4326 so it went unnoticed.

Comment: There is no time estimation to close the bug in the ticket. How much time will it take and what price are we talking about? If fixing this bug will be sponsored which GeoServer versions will be fixed? Would it be possible to patch existing installations?

Comment: please continue this on the geoserver-user list